# Why has paint started scraping off, how can I prevent it?

Tags: repair, paint, body-work

Here is a before and after I did of some damage to car.  All I did was spray it black, I didn't apply primer before, no clear coat, polish or wax.

I was scrubbing it in self car wash today with a big brush and noticed the higher layer(or original paint) peeling off.  This is probably because the scrub bush hooks underneath it easily. You can see some small white dots which came back aswell as whitening of some parts of original paint.

What should I do to the area to ensure the scrub bush wont peel of the original paint layer off in future?

Is this happening because theres clear coat which provides a layer to protect the paint from getting peeled off?  Or is this because theres no primer, polish wax etc?

[image: before]
[image: After]

Comment: Bumper cover needs good surface preparation and primer for paint to stick well.

Comment: @Moab I dont think its the lack of primer because the new non primer paint isnt coming off.  Its the old paint with primer underneath thats coming  peeling off during a car wash.